# Incorrect Android Button Width in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-button, android-tablelayout

I have a series of buttons I want to add to different rows in a TableLayout. Each button needs to have a different width. However, each button's width is being ultimately set to be equal to the button with the maximum width. Can someone let me know how to fix this please?

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_to_fill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/num_high"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

Java code:

```
    for (int i =0; i< 5; ++i){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
        t1.setText("cat: ");
        t1.setTextSize(12);
        row.addView(t1);
        Button b1 = new Button(this);

        b1.setText(numHighRisk.toString());
        b1.setTextSize(12);
        b1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        row.addView(b1);
        int width;
        if (i > 2)
            width = 20;
        else
            width = 40;
        int heightDp = (int) (25 * scale + 0.5f);
        int widthDp = (int) (width * scale + 0.5f);


        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = b1.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = heightDp;
        params.width = widthDp;
        b1.setLayoutParams(params);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        table.addView(row,rowParams);
    }
```

(Each button has the same width using this code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah in table layout all the items will have same size in order to make them properly aligned , you can do one  thing try giving margin to your button so that their size will reduce, different margin for different button.
For example,

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

With some experimentation, I was able to accomplish varying widths by first adding each button to a FrameLayout and then adding the FrameLayout to the row.